# How to visualize dataset with XML Annotation and use it for YOLOv5

Tags: xml, yolo, object-recognition

I'm working on custom training for YOLOv5. I want to train YOLOv5 with datasets from [UA-DETRAC](http://detrac-db.rit.albany.edu/download), which contains XML Annotation for a folder containing some images. How could I visualize the datasets XML Annotation like this

[image: datasets visualization]

and how to use it for YOLOv5 custom training? I have read [this](https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/yolo-v5-object-detection-on-a-custom-dataset-61d478bc08f9) tutorial, but this dataset only has 1 XML annotation each folder (which contains several images), not 1 XML for 1 image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can visualize all of your notations and images using the labelimg
https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

To convert the xml (pascal/voc format) to txt (yolo format) you can use the labelimg program, then click on the "pascal/voc" and it will change to "yolo format". Click in check image and save. The program will save in the yolo formatar the image that you are on.

For a automatized conversion, you can use this example as a template to write your own converter https://github.com/rafael-junio/mio-dataset-converter/blob/master/mio-dataset-converter.py

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the labelimg. how about the format of folder which contains several images, meanwhile the xml file only for the folder, not every images.

Comment: In my example you can see that i iterate over a single csv, you can do something like that.